# Meaning of あってほしい in this sentence

Tags: て-form, particle-で

> けれど、気が合うから。相手のことに探りは入れずただ話して、遊ぶことだけを望む。
>
> 変だけど、別にいいじゃないか。
>
> 友達って楽しいことを共有して笑い合うためにある、そういう明るくて優しいもので俺はあってほしいから。
>
> それがきっと、疲れてしまった時の救いになるんだって

友達って楽しいことを共有して笑い合うためにある

Here he explains friends are something that exist for the sake of spending time together and laughing together.

そういう明るくて優しいもので俺はあってほしいから
I'm really struggling to understand the structure of this sentence.

What is もので here ding with あってほしい? Is it 会う?

Answer (score 2):

This actually a use of the copula である, which is not one indivisible whole but made up of components で and ある, which can be split, as you may already be familiar with from the negative form で＋は＋ない.

'Friends are for sharing the fun things with and laughing together, I'd like them to be that kind of gentle and bright thing anyway.'

Why is 俺は between で and ある though? I feel it emphasizes that it's the speakers own opinion. I often find myself overusing a similar phrase, ～と僕・私は思います, when I write in Japanese.

Comment: So it isn't もので "because"?

Comment: @Blueshell No, もの is just "thing" here. Compare "優しいものである (It's a gentle thing)" and "優しいものであって欲しい  (I want it to be a gentle thing)", where this "it" is the general concept of 友達.